# escaping hyphens in php (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function which returns OEM data for lawn mowers...

```
public function fetch_all($oem) {
    global $pdo;

    $query = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT DISTINCT partnumber, cat_id FROM `oem` WHERE " . $oem . " = `oem`");
    $query -> execute();

    return $query -> fetchAll();
}
```

the problem is some of this OEM data has a hyphen, and I have noticed when this OEM data is passed into the function it breaks it and nothing is returned....

how can I fix this?

thank you

Comment: You are using prepared statements wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PDO, **DO NOT** use string concatenation to introduce arbitrary user data or you will create dangerous [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Use placeholders and pass an array into the `execute` function:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT partnumber, cat_id FROM oem WHERE oem=:oem");
$query->execute(array('oem' => $oem));
```

[Proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) is best done with a disciplined approach to specifying all user data as placeholders in queries whenever possible. The PDO driver will take care of escaping it as necessary.

Comment: thank you dude, that worked :)

I'm new to this, can I ask why concatenating onto the SQL is bad? is it a security thing?

Comment: Just make sure you're following this pattern with your other queries and those will work, too.